# How to open all files in a directory in Bourne shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, loops, directory, sh

How can I use the *relative path* or *absolute path* as a single command line argument in a shell script?

For example, suppose my shell script is on my Desktop and I want to loop through all the text files in a folder that is somewhere in the file system.

I tried `sh myshscript.sh /home/user/Desktop`, but this doesn't seem feasible. And how would I avoid directory names and file names with whitespace?

myshscript.sh contains:

```
for i in `ls`
do
    cat $i
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superficially, you might write:

```
cd "${1:-.}" || exit 1
for file in *
do
    cat "$file"
done
```

except you don't really need the `for` loop in this case:

```
cd "${1:-.}" || exit 1
cat *
```

would do the job. And you could avoid the `cd` operation with:

```
cat "${1:-.}"/*
```

which lists (`cat`s) all the files in the given directory, even if the directory or the file names contains spaces, newlines or other difficult to manage characters.  You can use any appropriate glob pattern in place of `*` — if you want files ending `.txt`, then use `*.txt` as the pattern, for example.

This breaks down if you might have so many files that the argument list is too long.  In that case, you probably need to use `find`:

```
find "${1:-.}" -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec cat {} +
```

(Note that `-maxdepth` is a GNU `find` extension.)

Avoid using `ls` to generate lists of file names, especially if the script has to be robust in the face of spaces, newlines etc in the names.

Answer (score 1):

Use a glob instead of ls, and quote the loop variable:

```
for i in "$1"/*.txt
do
    cat "$i"
done
```

PS: [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points this out.